# How to go to route with Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I need to query my server to see which view needs to be rendered for a given user. So I have this activate function on my ApplicationRoute to look up the correct view.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    Util.getNodeData(gVars.node);
  }
});
```

Here is my function that looks up the right view:

```
Util.getNodeData = function(node) {

  // blah blah, figure out we need to go to the 'building' view: #/building

  // how do I go there?

}
```

Or Maybe I am not going about this in the best manner? I was just going to change the url with some string replacement, but that doesn't seem like the ember way...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have 'building' in your route, like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    //...
    this.resource('building');
    //...
}
```

Add parameter to your function:

```
Util.getNodeData = function(node, router) {
    // ...
    router.transitionTo('building')
    // ...
}
```

Then fire it in your ApplicationRoute:

```
Util.getNodeData(gVars.node, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the url directly, the *ember way* is to use the route's redirect hook. Also it does not make sense to do this from `ApplicationRoute` but instead from some default route like `IndexRoute`.

See [Redirection](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/) in the Ember Routing Guide

Comment: the function doesnt run when put inside the redirect function of the IndexRoute. It also doesn't run inside the activate function of the IndexRoute.